# Karate API Framework - Calling function in another feature file

Tags: karate

Calling function in another feature file

Feature File 1 - featureFile1.feature

```
* def add2Number = 
"""
function (a,b){
var c = a+b;
return c}
"""
* def add3Number = 
"""
function (a,b c){
var d = add2Number(a,b) + c;
return d}
"""
```

Feature File 2 - featureFile2.feature

```
* def obj = call read(featureFile1.feature)
* print obj.add2Number(1,2) 
* print obj.add3Number(1,2,3)
```

"print obj.add2Number(1,2)" this line is working fine
"print obj.add3Number(1,2,3)" this line throwing error as below org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "add2Number" is not defined

Question:
The above code is just a sample function for explaining, The problem is when feature file 2 calling feature file 1 function A which calls internal function B of feature file 1, it throws "ReferenceError: "add2Number" is not defined"

Is there any solution

Comment: speaking for myself, there is no way I can diagnose these kinds of problems without seeing all the code. try to follow this process (or wait for someone else to help): https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: For explaining the issue i faced i have created the following repo Kindly check and help me if you can - https://github.com/Sudharsandhoni/KarateDemo

Comment: it is not as per the instructions. pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added my solution - https://github.com/Sudharsandhoni/KarateDemo,

Feature: Solution 1

Scenario: Solution 1
Description: To solve the error: 'org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "pi" is not defined'. Need to tell(define) what is pi in the calling file

- def find = call read("Feature1.feature")
- def pi = find.pi
- print find.areaOfCircle(5)
- print find.circumferenceOfCircle(5)

Eventhough i found a alternative way, if need to call the function which calls internal functions/variables then need to define the same in calling feature too.

if only used few of internal properties then it can be easy. but if count increases it is difficult to define all.

Waiting for any better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating separate scenarios for both functions in file 1 and have a tag name for each scenario.
Now using the tag and feature file names you can call that particular function/feature.